# SSH2 extension for PHP on Ubuntu16.04 not working

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, ssh2-exec

I try to use PHP + SSH2 extension to reboot my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I successfully install SSH2 extension:

[image]

And then I write the PHP code, It successfully logs in but not execute command.

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");

if(!($con = ssh2_connect("localhost", 22))){
echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {

if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "lam", "root")) {
    echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
} else {
    // allright, we're in!
    echo "okay: logged in...\n";

    // execute a command
    if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "reboot" ))) {
        echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
    } else {
        // collect returning data from command
        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $data = "";
        while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
            $data .= $buf;
        }
        fclose($stream);
    }
}
}
?>
```

[image]

I dont't know what problem because I do similar in Centos 7.0 it works.